# Why can't I use the (at)nickname in comments?

Tags: bug, comments

I've noticed this a few times now: When I write (at)nickname in a comment, it won't appear in the posted comment. To me it looks like SO disabled this functionality only for me, while I see other people's (at)someone frequently. Did I do anything wrong to cause this behavior, or is it just that I can't see my own (at)someones?

Comment: correct. It's a duplicate. How are we supposed to find these duplicates before creating them? I did do a search for related questions, but when nothing turned up, I decided to post a question myself. Now I feel bad for creating a duplicate, but there was no chance to find that other question, because the title of it is not related to the the title of my question.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to think in the same way someone else did when they posted their question. I think I did a search for something like `name comment strip`. It might have been the 3rd search I did. Earlier ones returned too much or nothing. At any rate, duplicates are not seen as bad in and of themselves precisely because there are multiple ways to formulate the same problem, different keywords that people will use.

Comment: @Zelphir don't feel bad about it - sometimes looking for stuff is harder than it should be - hopefully though, with this post having a different title and body text, will help others find the relevant post if they too have the same query. So - you've got your answer and you've also given another sign-post for the community to find it in future. Everyone wins!

Comment: A lot of times, people only find duplicates because they've actually seen the target post themselves.  So the longer people stick around, the easier it is to spot duplicates.  Which is why [meta-tag:dupehammer] is a thing.